# In java, why the byte type can use &0xff to do the unsigned right shift operation?

Tags: java, byte

I know, in Java, byte type, before doing a right shift operation, will convert into the int type firstly.

So in Java, we will get a incorrect answer for byte type's >>> operation.

For example,

```
byte b=(byte)0xf1;
byte c=(byte)(b>>4);
byte d=(byte)(b>>>4);
byte e=(byte)((b&0xff)>>4);
```

d's answer equal to c. but e's anser is correct. I can't think of the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said, Java always computes with `int`s or larger, so

Consider `b = 1111 0001` (note the top bit is set, so `b` is actually -15)

implicit cast to int:
`(int)b = 1111 .... 1111 0001`

do the right shift:
`(b>>4)  = 1111 1111 .... 1111 1111`
`(b>>>4) = 0000 1111 .... 1111 1111`

explicit cast to bool:
`c = d = 1111 1111`.

---

consider `e=(byte)((b&0xff)>>4);`

implicit cast to int:
`(int)b = 1111 .... .... 1111 0001`

AND with 0xff:
`x&0xff = 0000 .... 0000 1111 0001`

do the right shift:
`(b&0xff)>>4 = 0000 .... 0000 1111`

explicit cast to byte:
`e = 0000 1111`

Answer (score 0):

The smallest type in java is int. It's partly because CPUs work with integers or greater types nowadays.
As a result JVM was implemented based on int and other smaller data types like byte, char, boolean were added for convenience only.

So when you do bit operations you can enjoy inconsistencies like you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question yourself "before doing a right shift operation, will convert into the int type firstly", so

```
byte e=(byte)((b&0xff)>>4);
```

firstly

```
b -> int => 0xfffffff1
```

then

```
0xfffffff1 & 0xff => 0xf1
```

then

```
0xf1 >> 4 => 0xf
```